# C program to count number of n-letter words in a text stuck in nested while loop

Tags: c, getchar

I'm getting back into coding after quite a few years out of school and I'm stuck trying to write a program in C that counts how many n-letter words are in a text, storing them into a length n array and then printing them. To keep is simple, I've assumed n is b/w 1 and 10 and each word is seperated by exactly one space.

Here's the code, However, it seems my program never gets out of the inner while loop so nothing is printed on the screen. I tried printing something at the end of that loop to test it and for some reason the program prints it as many times as there are characters (including spaces, which the inner while condition should catch and exit). Am I overlooking something here?

```
main()
{
int c, i, j, counter;
counter = 0;
int wlength [10];
for (i=0; i<10; ++i) //initialize array
    wlength[i]=0;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF){ // keep taking input until end of file
    while (c!=' '){   //keep counting until you reach the end of the word
        ++counter;
        c=getchar(); 
    }
    wlength [counter-1]++;  //increment the counter for that word length
    counter=0 ; //reset the counter for the next word
}
for (j=0;j<10;++j) //print the array
    printf("%d ", wlength[j]);
```

Comment: You need to test for EOF.  You only test in the outer loop.

Comment: Isn't the last char of each line a newline (\n or \r\n) ?

Comment: try `while (c!=' ' && c!= '\n' && c!= EOF){` instead of `while (c!=' '){`

Comment: Im not sure how large the files are, but this method is very slow. You normally don't want to read byte by byte. Read  block (>4k) by block, or read the file in memory in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and the tip!), that was it! I'm not coding this to do actual work, it's just one of the early exercises in K&R... I'm getting my feet wet again as I haven't coded much since I left school a few years ago, you can see that I'm rusty! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word count program - stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015903/word-count-program-stdin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops reading standard input, and only one checks for `EOF`. So your program reads the file and gets stuck if there isn't **exactly** a space before the end of the file.
You would be better off with only one loop, replacing the other by an `if - else` statement :

```
Pseudo-code :
while ( getchar  and !EOF )
{
    if ( char isn't a space )
    {
        increment counter
    } else {
        increment value for given length
        set first counter to 0
    }
}
```

You should also check that you're in the bounds of your array... Words like 'expotentially` exist ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yea, seems I had forgotten to add checks for both EOF and newline in the inner loop. The if-else statement option is also a good point (as is expotentially!!) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `inner while loop`. Because in unix or unix-like system. At the end of each line is `\n`. so your code is blocked in the first inner loop. you need to add more check on that. The test condition should change to:

```
while(c != ' ' && c != '\n'){
    ++counter;
    c=getchar();
}
```

And I ran that, it worked.

Comment: Yes, thats what we said ;-) But, understand that the file normally can easily contain a CR+LF (\r\n). So this code is not enough...

Comment: @Rogier Windows use the `CR+LF` at the end of line. If you have the `mingw` or `cygwin` on Windows.  Can use `dos2unix` command to convert it. But consider more portable, the condition may need to add more.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Seems like I had forgotten both the new line and EOF condition in the inner while loop. I should have specified that I'm using a windows machine and running it in an IDE (Code::Blocks).