# Word count program - stdin

Tags: c, eof, getchar

For below [question](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node7.html#SECTION00730000000000000000),

> Write a program to read English text to end-of-data (type control-D to indicate end of data at a terminal, see below for detecting it), and print a count of word lengths, i.e. the total number of words of length 1 which occurred, the number of length 2, and so on.
>
> Define a word to be a sequence of alphabetic characters. You should allow for word lengths up to 25 letters.
>
> Typical output should be like this:
>
> ```
>         length 1 : 10 occurrences
>         length 2 : 19 occurrences
>   length 3 : 127 occurrences
>      length 4 : 0 occurrences
>         length 5 : 18 occurrences
>         ....
> ```
>
> To read characters to end of data see above question.

---

Here is my working solution,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char ch;
  short wordCount[20] = {0};
  int count = 0;
  while(ch = getchar(), ch >= 0){
    if(ch == ' ' || ch == ',' || ch == ';'|| ch == ':'|| ch == '.'|| ch == '/'){
      wordCount[count]++;
      count=0;
    }else{
      count++;
    }
  }
  wordCount[count]++; // Incrementing here looks weird to me

  for(short i=1; i< sizeof(wordCount)/sizeof(short); i++){
    printf("\nlength %d : %d occurences",i, wordCount[i]);
  }
}
```

---

Question:

1)

From code elegance aspect, Can I avoid incrementing(++) `wordCount` outside `while` loop?

2)

Can I make `wordCount` array size more dynamic based on word size, rather than constant size `20`?

*Note: Learnt about `struct` but am yet to learn dynamic structures like `Linkedlist`*

Comment: `while(ch = getchar(), ch >= 0)` should be `while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` and `ch` should be an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: @mch Wrt your conditional expression, I will miss last word with this condition. Dont I?

Comment: @mch `int`  will implicitly convert to `char`. C is loosely typed language. Is that a problem?

Comment: You can create a structure like `struct desc {int len; int count;}` and keep a  list or another dynamic structure to keep a number of these structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dynamic allocations you can start with space for 20 `shorts` (although the problem statement appears to ask for you to allow for words up to 25 characters):

```
short maxWord = 20;
short *wordCount = malloc(sizeof(*wordCount) * maxWord);
```

Then, when you increment `count` you can allocate more space if the current word is longer than can be counted in your dynamic array:

```
} else {
    count++;
    if (count >= maxWord) {
        maxWord++;
        wordCount = realloc(sizeof(*wordCount) * maxWord);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `free(wordCount)` when you are done.

Since you don't need to count zero-length words, you might consider modifying your code so that `wordCount[0]` stores the number of words of length 1, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To 1):
 maybe scan from one delimiting character to the next until you increment `wordCount`. Make `EOF` a delimiting character as well.

To 2)
 you can scan the file twice and then decide how much memory you need. Or you dynamically `realloc` whenever the more memory is needed. This is something the `std::array` class does internally for example.

Also you should think about what happens if there are two  characters after one another. Right now you would count this as a word.

Comment: `std::array` is C++.

Comment: so what? I said use the concept that this class uses, not use the class ;)